# Combine Variable - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to combine two string and make it as a current variable and get the data from it? I'm not sure if there's another way to do this. If there's any, please let me know.

Here's my code.

```
$App1 = "Google Chrome"
$App2 = "Mozilla"
$AppExt1 = ".exe"
$AppExt2 = ".msi"
$Apps = @('1','2')
ForEach ($Applications in $Apps) {
    $AppToBeInstalled = '$App' + $_
    $AppExt = '$AppExt' + $_
    Write-Host "Application $AppToBeInstalled to be installed with extension $AppExt"
}
```

What I want.

```
Application Google Chrome to be installed with extension .exe
Application Mozilla to be installed with extension .msi
```

But I'm only getting empty result.

```
Application  to be installed with extension 
Application  to be installed with extension
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable, though quite unorthodox, you can use [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable?view=powershell-7.2) to get variables using dynamic names:

```
$App1 = "Google Chrome"
$App2 = "Mozilla"
$AppExt1 = ".exe"
$AppExt2 = ".msi"
$Apps = @('1','2')

ForEach ($Applications in $Apps) {
    $AppToBeInstalled = (Get-Variable App$Applications).Value
    $AppExt = (Get-Variable AppExt$Applications).Value
    Write-Host "Application $AppToBeInstalled to be installed with extension $AppExt"
}

> Application Google Chrome to be installed with extension .exe
> Application Mozilla to be installed with extension .msi
```

What might be a more common approach to this would be to use a [`hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$map = @{
    "Google Chrome" = ".exe"
    "Mozilla" = ".msi"
}

ForEach ($key in $map.Keys) {
    $AppToBeInstalled = $key
    $AppExt = $map[$key]
    Write-Host "Application $AppToBeInstalled to be installed with extension $AppExt"
}

> Application Google Chrome to be installed with extension .exe
> Application Mozilla to be installed with extension .msi
```

Comment: @Mr.Rak happy to help. Note that, in case you're going to use the `Get-Variable` method instead of a `hashtable`, consider using the `-ValueOnly` switch instead of `(Get-Var...).Value` as [Vojin Purić](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70221441/15339544) pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can you can use

```
Get-Variable -Name "nameOfVar" -ValueOnly
```

in your case it would look something like

```
$App1 = "Google Chrome"
$App2 = "Mozilla"
$AppExt1 = ".exe"
$AppExt2 = ".msi"
$Apps = @('1','2')
ForEach ($Applications in $Apps) {
    $AppToBeInstalled = Get-Variable -Name "App$Applications" -ValueOnly
    $AppExt = Get-Variable -Name "AppExt$Applications" -ValueOnly
    Write-Host "Application $AppToBeInstalled to be installed with extension $AppExt"
}
```

Comment: This is also working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As some people mentioned you can create custom variables then call them from within the for loop:

```
$App1 = [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = "Google Chrome"
    Ext = ".exe"
}
$App2 = [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = "Mozilla"
    Ext = ".msi"
}

$Apps=@($App1,$App2)

ForEach ($App in $Apps) {
    $AppName = $App.Name
    $AppExt = $App.Ext
    Write-Host "Application $AppName to be installed with extension $AppExt"
}
```

Output will be:

> Application Google Chrome to be installed with extension .exe
> Application Mozilla to be installed with extension .msi

Might make it easier if you have to keep adding more apps to the script in the future.

Comment: This is nice and more easy to follow. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.